# Git flow small fixs

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm studying **Git Flow** and I don't understand one thing: I'm developing a new feature inside a branch, lets say `features/wowFeature`, when I found a small css bug that need to be fixed. I have two questions:

1. Where am I supposed to do this small fix? Inside a branch named `features/cssFix`? Because it's not really a feature. Moreover, should I branch `features/wowFeature` or `develop`?
2. After fix is complete I can merge it to `develop` branch but I won't have it inside my branch `features/wowFeature`.. I don't like that, if I have to work to this branch for one month I will always see the small css bug. Should I merge `features/cssFix` to `develop` and `develop` to `features/wowFeature`, should I merge `features/cssFix` to `develop` and then to `features/wowFeature` or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers for questions like that will be always be partially
opinions-based. Let me present my view on it.

> Where am I supposed to do this small fix? Inside a branch named
>   features/cssFix?

Yes.

> Because it's not really a feature.

You can create new branches not only for adding new features but also
for other purposes such as proofs of concept or fixes.  I understand
that you might be concerned about the name - indeed, feature != fix.
However, it's not a big problem I think and might be hard to solve in
some systems that integrate bug tracker with code repository (for
example Bitbucket and JIRA) and require branches to always start with a
given prefix in order to be able to present link to the pull request in bug tracker and a link to bug tracker in the pull request.

> Moreover, should I branch features/wowFeature or develop?

`develop`, code at `features/wowFeature` is not production-ready yet.

> Should I merge features/cssFix to develop and develop to
>     features/wowFeature, should I merge features/cssFix to develop and
>     then to features/wowFeature or something else?

If you assume that `features/cssFix` will be always merged first into
`develop`, for example because your team considers them more important
and acts faster on them you should locally *rebase* - not *merge* your
`features/wowFeature` onto `develop` and test it again before pushing
it to the review.  It's always possible that the quick fix already
merged into `develop` will somehow impact the new feature.

Answer (score 1):

is the css bug present in your releases? if that's the case you might have to use a branch created from master... but let's assume that you will work on development. The normal flow would be that you create a branch from develop just to correct that problem. Create a PR and then merge to develop. Then, your branch can take advantage of it by rebasing after it has been merged to develop. You could even go as far as to cherry-pick the change while it is pending to be merged to develop, but that adds up a little more effort on your part to avoid carrying it over when you either rebase or clean up the branch. It's possible, only requires extra attention to detail.